# finding the postcode that the user spent the most time at

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table:

- UserID
- Postcode
- Hours at postcode

I need to be able to find the one that the user spent most time at. I've tried a max function, then I thought about ordering by hours Desc and taking the top one, but I am not getting anywhere,

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output two records if user spent equal max hours on two poscodes:

```
select
     UserID,
     Postcode,
     Hours
from
(
select 
    UserID,
    Postcode,
    Hours,
    dense_rank() over(partition by userId order by hours desc) rn
 from (select --skip this subquery if hours already aggregated by user, postcode
             UserID, Postcode, sum(Hours) hours
         from table group by UserID, Postcode
      ) s
    )s
where rn = 1;
```

Use `row_number() over(partition by userId order by hours desc) rn` instead of `dense_rank()` if you need single record per user.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it very almost works - but I still get multiple results for some users (up to 23 postcodes) which is very strange!

Comment: @kikee1222 Use row_number()  instead of dense_rank() if you need one record per user_id. dense_rank will mark as 1 all max hour postcodes per user_id if hours are equal, row_number will pick only one record. I mentioned the same in the answer.